# I want to know why merge join cannot be done without equal sign(=) on ON clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm recently studying SQL Server. I read a book and it says that merge join requires at least one equal sign(=) on ON clause in SQL Server.

So, I tried this query below and I found that the error occurs.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TABLE_1 AS T1 
        INNER MERGE JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2 
        ON T1.COL_1 > T2.COL_2
```

Error Message:

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 6  Query processor could not produce
> a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the
> query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

And this book also says this can be done in case of Full Outer Join.
So I tried this query below and found it committed successfully with no errors.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TABLE_1 AS T1 
        FULL OUTER MERGE JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2 
        ON T1.COL_1 > T2.COL_2
```

I tried to search for the reason but I couldn't find any explanation about this.

Can anyone tell me why SQL Server doesn't allow merge join without an equality operator unless it's full outer join?

Thank you for reading my question

Answer (score 1):

You used **Inner Merge Join**. Merge clause is a join hint that tells sql engine to work more efficient.

Merge joins have the fastest algorithm since each row only needs to be read once from the source inputs.  Also, optimizations occurring in other join operators can give those operators better performance under certain conditions.

if you must use '>' operator, use **regular Inner Join**, like this.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TABLE_1 AS T1 
        INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2 
        ON T1.COL_1 > T2.COL_2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you one more question? So the reason we can't use inner merge join with other operators is because the optimizer decided it would be less efficient than regular join?

Comment: This restrction is visualized in this link [link](https://bertwagner.com/2018/12/18/visualizing-merge-join-internals-and-understanding-their-implications/)

Comment: I checked out that link you gave, and it helped me a lot. Thank you for your help :)